# make file Java "missing operator" "none to do with default"

Tags: java, cmake, makefile

I am trying to build a make file for my program and Im getting the error missing operator at line 4 (javac $(JFLAGS)). I am also getting the error "none to do with default". Can someone help me with this error please? i have been stuck for quite a bit. Thank you much

```
JFLAGS = -g -d
JC = javac
%.class : %.java
    javac $(JFLAGS)

CLASSES = \
    Hello.java

default: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

Comment: You don't pass the files to the `javac` command. You just run `javac -g -d` which presumably isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Before I had $(JFLAGS) $(JC) $*.java but it was giving me the same issue.

Comment: `$(JFLAGS) $(JC)` $*.java` would appear to have the arguments and command backwards. Assuming `javac` wants the `.java` file as argument and outputs a matching `.class` by default then you probably want `$(JC) $(JFLAGS) $<`.

Comment: When asking questions please always cut and paste the actual command you ran and the complete, exact error you received.  Depending on the exact text and syntax of the "error missing operator at line 4" various different things could be true.  Also, you should remove the `cmake` tag from this question: it has no relationship to cmake at all that I can see.

Comment: @Roddrick I take it the answer to your question was in my answer. It would be helpful if you could update your question with the exact errors so that somebody looking for them in the future will have an easier time at finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention you are getting the error

> make: Nothing to be done for 'default'.

This is **not** an error. It is `make` telling you that the target `default` is up to date and none of its prerequisites are older than it or need to be remade. For your particular case this will occur when the file `Hello.class` already exists in the **same** directory as your `makefile`. It is **not** an error but a simple message from `make`.

---

With regards to your other error

> Java: missing operator at line 4

might this possibly say

> makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.

instead? If that is the case then it means that you have not correctly indented the line

```
javac $(JFLAGS)
```

with a tab character.

**Note**: I mention this because it appears to be the closest error message to what you have described that I can replicate.

---

Another more pressing issue than the above is in particular your use of `javac $(JFLAGS)` and `JFLAGS`. In `JFLAGS` you have specified the `-d` option. When you execute `javac $(JFLAGS)` the error you get should look similar to

```console
$ javac -g -d
javac: -d requires an argument
```

This is because the `-d` option when passed to `javac` is used to tell `javac` where the output directory that it should place `.class` files is. If you **want** your `.class` files to be output in the same directory as your `makefile` relative to their package name (see below) then you need to delete the `-d` option and declare `JFLAGS` as

```
JFLAGS = -g
```

If however, you **dont** want your `.class` files to be output in the same directory as your `makefile` then you need to declare a directory after the `-d` option in `JFLAGS` as

```
JFLAGS = -g -d /path/to/my/output/directory
```

Now that we've covered the `-d` option let's move on to actually compiling your `.java` files. The current rule you have is

```
%.class : %.java
    javac $(JFLAGS)
```

this should to be altered to

```
%.class : %.java
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $<
```

The automatic variable `$<` stands for the first prerequisite and will create a command like

```
$ javac -g Hello.java
```

for your particular example, which will create a `Hello.class` file in the same directory as the `makefile` and your `Hello.java` file.